# Is there a way to make this code faster and if possible avoid loops?

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, matrix, runtime

`A1`, `B1`, `C1`, `A2`, `B2` and `C2` are **6** matrix with the same dimensions `4435X2000`.

I have to find the values `i`, `j` and `k` for which `A1(k,2000) == A2(i,j)` and `B1(k,2000) == B2(i,j)` and `C1(k,2000) == C2(i,j)` , with the condition `X(k)==1` and `Y(i,j)==1`

The objective is to find: **counter**, **L**, **T** and **D**

Is there a way to make this code faster? Can I avoid loops?

```
counter=0;
L(1)=0;
T(1)=0;
D(1)=0;

for k=1:4435
    if X(k)==1      % X is a vector (4435x1)
       F(k,:) = [A1(k,2000) B1(k,2000) C1(k,2000)] 
       for i=1:4435
           for j=100:1999
               if Y(i,j)==1      % Y is a matrix (4435x1999)
                  if F(k,:) == [A2(i,j) B2(i,j) C2(i,j)]
                     counter = counter+1;
                     L(counter)=k;
                     T(counter)=i;
                     D(counter)=j;
                  end 
               end
           end
       end
    end 
end
```

**I want a solution that will save me at least 80% of the computation time!**
**and not have the error message: Out of memory**

Comment: What are the actual datasizes for the variables used in it?

Comment: @Divakar: For A1,A2,B1,B2,C1 and C2: 4435x2000

Comment: `if F(k,:) ==` probably instead of `if F(k,:) =`? And that's an array comparison there and not a scalar comparison, right?

Comment: @Divakar: yes, I forgot one =

Comment: @bzak: is `X` a function or variable?

Comment: @Daniel: X and Y are functions that depend on other variables. but it is an expressions like: (A==2 && B>5 && C<10)

Comment: @bzak: Not having these functions makes it difficult. Do they support vectorized operations? For example `X(1:3)` instead of `[X(1),X(2),X(3)]`? Besides the possibility to vectorize, you should preallocate your variables.

Comment: @bzak Putting Daniel's words in other way - Can you feed arrays to `X` and `Y` that is can you get 1D array with `X(1:4435)` and 2D array as output with `Y(1:4435,100:1999)`? Would that be the bottleneck instead?

Comment: @Divakar: I think I can do it

Comment: @Daniel: yes, X and Y support vectorized operations.

Comment: Instead of showing us code, could you perhaps explain what the code is doing in plain English?  That way, we are open to doing something entirely different and we can still accomplish what your main objective is. We can also possibly optimize what you're doing even further if we aren't constrained to making your particular method of doing things optimized.

Comment: @rayryeng: I think my code is not too complicated to understand. I have to find the values i, j and k for which A1(k,2000) == A2(i, j) and B1(k,2000) == B2(i, j) and C1(k,2000) == C2(i, j) ,  with the condition X(k)==1 and Y(i,j)==1

Comment: Ah gotcha. That makes more sense!

Comment: Do you need two loops with `for k=1:4435` and `for i=1:4435`?

Comment: @Divakar: yes Divakar, k for A1,B1 and C1, and i for A2,B2 and C2

Comment: @Divakar: I remain open to proposals that meet my objective! (I have to find the values i, j and k for which A1(k,2000) == A2(i,j) and B1(k,2000) == B2(i,j) and C1(k,2000) == C2(i,j) , with the condition X(k)==1 and Y(i,j)==1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how this works out for you -

```
%// Store X-Y data by calling X() and Y() functions
X_data = X(1:4435);
Y_data = Y(1:4435,100:1999);

range1 = 100:1999 %// define range for columns
A2 = A2(:,range1); %// Crop out A2, B2, C2 based on column-range
B2 = B2(:,range1);
C2 = C2(:,range1);
Y_data = Y_data(:,range1)==1;

%// Indices for dim-3
idx_X = find(X_data==1) 

%// Map X==1 onto A1, B1, C1
A1Lr = A1(X_data==1,end)
B1Lr = B1(X_data==1,end)
C1Lr = C1(X_data==1,end)

%// Setup output array to store L, T, D as single Nx3 output array
out = zeros(sum(Y_data(:))*numel(A1Lr),3);
%// Try out(sum(Y_data(:)==1)*numel(A1Lr),3)=0; instead for speed!

%// Start collecting output indices
count = 1;
for iter1 = 1:numel(A1Lr)
    [R,C] = find(Y_data & A2==A1Lr(iter1) & B2==B1Lr(iter1) & C2==C1Lr(iter1));
    nR = numel(R);
    out(count:count+nR-1,:) = [R C repmat(iter1,nR,1)];
    count = count + nR;
end
out(find(out(:,1)==0,1):end,:)=[];

%// Packup the outputs
T = out(:,1)
D = out(:,2) + range1(1)-1
L = idx_X(out(:,3))
```

Comment: @bzak What's the size of `Y_data`?

Comment: 4435x1900 and range1 : 1x1900

Comment: @bzak Ah I am sorry my bad! Change that line from `Y_data = Y_data(:,range1)==1;` to `Y_data = Y_data==1;` and see if it works?

Comment: ??? Error using ==> zeros
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> out = zeros(sum(Y_data(:))*numel(A1Lr),3);  and sorry if  you spend too much time on my questions!!!

Comment: @bzak It's ok, don't worry! :) See if [this](http://pastebin.com/h0CCLEuN) works?

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to determine what your code is actually supposed to accomplish, without really working to interpret your code. However, I'll give it a crack:

```
% Determine where X is true.
XTrue = X == 1;

% Extract values from A1,B1,C1 where X is true.
F ( XTrue , 1 : 3 ) = [ A1(XTrue,2000) B1(XTrue,2000) C1(XTrue,2000) ];

% Determine where Y is true.
YTrueIndex = find ( Y == 1 );

% Determine where the extracted values match
counter = [];
L = [];
T = [];
D = [];

for ( ii = 1 : length(YTrueIndex) )
  indexCurrent = YTrueIndex(ii)
  FRowsThatMatch = F(:,1)==A2(indexCurrent) & F(:,2)==B2(indexCurrent) & F(:,3)==C2(indexCurrent);

  matchCount = length ( find ( FRowsThatMatch ) );

  if ( matchCount > 0 )
    counter = counter + matchCount;

    [ i , j ] = ind2sub ( size ( Y ) , indexCurrent );
    L = [ L , find ( FRowsThatMatch ) ];
    T = [ T , ones(matchCount,1)*i ];
    D = [ D , ones(matchCount,2)*j ];
  end
end
```

Comment: I have to run my program with your answer before knowing if it works or not. usually with my code I have to wait five hours before getting a result !!!

Comment: It might be buggy, but its a start getting rid of a couple of the loopa.

Comment: ??? Error using ==> find
Not enough input arguments.

Error in ==> L = [ L , find ( FRowsThatMatch ) ];

Comment: That is probably because of the spacing... MATLAB is inconsistent in its whitespace allowances. find(FRowsThatMatch)

Comment: ??? Error using ==> horzcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==>    D = [ D , ones(matchCount,2)*j ];

Comment: Yup, another bad. Use ".*" instead of " *". For both T and D.

Comment: ??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==>    L = [L,find(FRowsThatMatch)];